# Pycharm doesnt auto complete cv2 package

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, autocomplete, pycharm

I just installed Pycharm 2017 professional to work with python 2.7 version and
currently installed opencv on my computer.
finally i succeeded to make OpenCV works on pycharm but I still got an issue that pycharm doesnt auto complete the commands i write which make it a lil bit pain i the a**.
I've attached [image: an image]  which shows on the left that pycharm recognized numpy package but on the right it doesnt recognized cv2.
Hope you got answers.
Thanks!